# Low performance in ASP.NET web base application

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik, web-user-controls

Our team is developing a medical product. We are using Telerik Rad controls for the user interface. Actually my task is to find the reason behind the lack of speed and performance in a specific module.

That module is actually containing the chain of user controls. Main Parent (user control) in which there is rad tabs. and each tab have different controls, and that controls also may or may not contain further child controls. actually in my case 2 or 3 tabs have further child controls.

Whenever i run the parent control it cause slow speed of the application. it's take almost 9 to 10 seconds to load first time which is ridiculous, and after that it's take 3 to 4 seconds.

The problem is that we have same such module in our application have less tabs but they loading and running within one second that is perfect. We interact the db and i think there is no such issue with the data fetch time. DB interaction is perfect, queries are fine no use of such query that cause increase in time.

I think this is the issue of Asp.net User controls. What are the things cause slow speed? What i need to check? Please help me out in this.

[image: User Controls]

Comment: Have you tried the following to improve performance? Caching data that are for lookup purpose, reduce the number of db connection open and close, minify css and js files, turn ViewState off for controls that don't need it, like labels. Use Trace to trackdown the slowest part of the page and improve it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make heavy use of client side code it would be a good idea to do some profiling of the JavaScript code. JQuery selectors etc.. JavaScript and selectors can slow down as the DOM grows larger if not optimized.

Comment: Actually we are not using javascript or jquery or Jason.

Comment: Could it perhaps be due to a large viewstate from all the controls on the tabs? Is it ASP.Net web forms or MVC?

Comment: It is asp.net web forms application. Yeh good idea it may be due to large viewstate  in all the controls.

Comment: you could try loading controls on a tab changed using jQuery.Load() function. try to load different controls on something changed. And also check the viewstate and disable it for thoses controls which don't need viewstate

Comment: what about caching? like output cache on the page or data cache?